# Print data from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a report in a datatable. I need to send this to a printer and print it.

Comment: You have a report in a datatable - in what form? As a byte array in a field?

Comment: I am running a query in SQL server to get the datatable. I need to print it now. I am giving a print button in my User Interface, which would handle printing. I do not want to print through the gridview on my page. Need to use the table only.

Answer (score 1):

Really not much better than Ctrl+P or JavaScript's [window.print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536672%28v=vs.85%29)

Create separate printing [CSS with media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) and have whatever layout you want specifically for printing.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="defaultStyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="printStyles.css">
```

Comment: I need the code for sending data from my datatable to the printer. Could you please help me with that? Styling is not required.